# WPF : how to do data binding for 2 textbox with single class having 2 objects

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

## Environment

Microsoft visual studio 2017
Windows 7

## Problem/Goal

I want to do data binding with the txtboxes with the single class objects.

## XAML

```
  <!--User 1 config-->
  <GroupBox  Name="grpBoxUser1" Margin="10,10,10,10" FontSize="16" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
<GroupBox.Header>
    <TextBlock FontWeight="DemiBold" Foreground="Navy"> User 1 config</TextBlock>
</GroupBox.Header>
<Grid ShowGridLines="False">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="IP address: " Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="TCP port: " Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="Username: " Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="Password: " Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="UserConnectionStatus" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" 
                       FontSize="12" FontWeight="DemiBold" Margin="4"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                       Text="{Binding Path= UserStatus}"
                       />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" FontSize="12" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Margin="10" Name="UserTestButton" 
                    Content="Test" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="60"
                    Click="checkUserStatus"
                     />
    <!--<TextBlock Text="Pre-defined Layout: " Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4"></TextBlock>-->
    <TextBox Name="textboxIP1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                     FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4" Width="100"
                     Text="{Binding IP}"
                     PreviewTextInput="TextboxIP1PreviewTextInput" 
                     />
    <TextBox Name="textboxPort1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="12"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4" Width="50"
                     Text="{Binding PORT}" 
                     PreviewTextInput="TextboxPort1PreviewTextInput"
                     />
    <TextBox Name="textboxUser1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4" Width="100"
                      Text="{Binding User_Username}"
                     />
    <PasswordBox Name="textboxPass1" PasswordChar="*" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4" Width="100" 
                      />
    <!--<ComboBox Name="combo1"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
                      FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4" Width="100"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource layoutDataProvider}}">
            </ComboBox>-->
</Grid>
```

```
 <!--User 2 config-->
 <GroupBox  Name="grpBoxUser2" Margin="10,10,10,10" FontSize="16" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
<GroupBox.Header>
    <TextBlock FontWeight="DemiBold" Foreground="Navy"> User 2 config</TextBlock>
</GroupBox.Header>
<Grid ShowGridLines="False">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="IP address: " Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="TCP port: " Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="Username: " Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="Password: " Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4"></TextBlock>
    <TextBox Name="textboxIP2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                     FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4" Width="100"
                     Text="{Binding IP_User2}"
                     PreviewTextInput="TextboxIP1PreviewTextInput" />

    <TextBox Name="textboxPort2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="12"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4" Width="50"
                     Text="{Binding PORT_User2}" 
                     PreviewTextInput="TextboxPort1PreviewTextInput"/>

    <TextBox Name="textboxUser2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="12" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4" Width="100"
                     Text="{Binding User_Username_User2}"/>

    <PasswordBox Name="textboxPass2" PasswordChar="*" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" 
                         FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4" Width="100" />

    <Button Grid.Row="1" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Margin="10" Name="UserTestButtonUser2" 
                    Content="Test" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="60"
                    Click="checkUserStatus" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="4"
                     />
</Grid>
```

## Class (Now)

```
  using System;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Xml;
  using System.Xml.Serialization;

  namespace App
  {
public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Properties

    #region Private members

    private string _ip;
    private string _port;
    private string _username;
    private string _pass;

    private string _ip2;
    private string _port2;
    private string _username2;
    private string _pass2;

    #endregion

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// IP Address of the User
    /// </summary>
    public string IP
    {
        get { return _ip; }
        set
        {
            _ip = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IP");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// User Port number
    /// </summary>
    public string PORT
    {
        get { return _port; }
        set
        {
            _port = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("PORT");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// User  Login Username
    /// </summary>
    public string User_Username
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set
        {
            _username = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("User_Username");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// User Login password
    /// </summary>
    public string User_Pass
    {
        get { return _pass; }
        set
        {
            _pass = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("User_Pass");
        }
    }


    public string IP_User2
    {
        get { return _ip2; }
        set
        {
            _ip2 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IP_User2");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// User Port number
    /// </summary>
    public string PORT_User2
    {
        get { return _port2; }
        set
        {
            _port2 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("PORT_User2");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// User  Login Username
    /// </summary>
    public string User_Username_User2
    {
        get { return _username2; }
        set
        {
            _username2 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("User_Username_User2");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// User Login password
    /// </summary>
    public string User_Pass_User2
    {
        get { return _pass2; }
        set
        {
            _pass2 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("User_Pass_User2");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public UserViewModel()
    {
    }
    #endregion

}
```

}

## GOAL

## Class(want to refactor somewhat like this )

I want to refactor like below class. So that I can use the single class and create 2 objects for it and then bind those 2 objects with UI.

```
 using System;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Xml;
 using System.Xml.Serialization;

 namespace App
 {
     public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Properties

    #region Private members

    private string _ip;
    private string _port;
    private string _username;
    private string _pass;

    #endregion

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// IP Address of the User
    /// </summary>
    public string IP
    {
        get { return _ip; }
        set
        {
            _ip = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IP");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// User Port number
    /// </summary>
    public string PORT
    {
        get { return _port; }
        set
        {
            _port = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("PORT");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// User  Login Username
    /// </summary>
    public string User_Username
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set
        {
            _username = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("User_Username");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// User Login password
    /// </summary>
    public string User_Pass
    {
        get { return _pass; }
        set
        {
            _pass = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("User_Pass");
        }
    }
    
    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public UserViewModel()
    {
    }
    #endregion

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    // Your both objects of UserViewModel are in this class.
    // Lets say U1 and U2
}
```

Now you XAML's DataContext would be MainViewModel and bind Groupbox's DataContext to U1 and U2

```
<GroupBox  Name="grpBoxUser2" Margin="10,10,10,10" FontSize="16" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" DataContext="{Binding U1}">
<GroupBox  Name="grpBoxUser2" Margin="10,10,10,10" FontSize="16" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" DataContext="{Binding U2}">
```

Now your GroupBox's control would have the context of UserViewModel.

Comment: is U1 and U2 are objects ? or are they U1 class and U2 class ?